# How can I control what is passed to the OnCreate() method when a command or tool is initialized?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, arcgis-engine

In an ArcEngine application can I control what is passed to the OnCreate() method when a command or tool is initialized?

(I am using a synchronization object because I have both a map and a pagelayout in my form.  Rather than just passing the active control I would prefer to just pass the synchronizer because it contains all the controls.)

Comment: If anyone is interested!   

tools = new ToolbarMenuClass();
tools.CommandPool = toolsView.CommandPool;
tools.SetHook( <Your[ComVisible( true )]Object> );

Comment: If anyone is interested! 

If toolsView is your AxToolbarControl, this sets the Hook:

tools = new ToolbarMenuClass(); 
tools.CommandPool = toolsView.CommandPool; 
tools.SetHook( <Your[ComVisible( true )]Object> );

However! (This does NOT work! OnCreate() never gets called. Is it necessary to implement a specific interface in your passed object? Don't know...  )

Comment: IHookHelper.Hook says: 
a menu hook must support IToolbarControl or IToolbarBuddy

No dice, however, as even after implementing IToolbarBuddy the OnCreate never gets called.

Comment: Rather than add new information as comments, can you revise your Question so that only it needs to be read by potential answerers, please?  Before anyone provides an Answer is the best time to do this.